# 'Object does not support property or method 'fnGetPosition'

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to use this on a datatable but for some reason am getting the error in the title

My datatable is oTable

```
$('#homesTable').on('click', 'a.dtDelete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition($(this).closest('tr').get(0));
    homeId = oTable.fnGetData(aPos, 0);
    alert("Suspend home: " + homeId);
});
```

I've used this many times before but for some reason it is not working, my datatable is loading in fine with its data

Comment: Can you show how you initialize your table? If you use `DataTable()`, use `dataTable()` instead, since `fnGetPosition()` is an older API method.

Comment: oTable = $('#homesTable').dataTable(myObject);

Comment: This must be a scope issue, Is your initialisation code AND the click event code within `$(document).ready`$(document).ready`?